# Finding a marginal PDF

Tags: probability-distributions

If we have a Random variable X that is $$2e^{-2x}$$ and Y that is an exponential distribution with X as its parameter $\lambda$, then how do we go around solving this question? I thought that we should find its CDF first by using $$P[Xe^{-XY} < Y] $$ but then I run into the issue of how to get X on one side. I took the log  $$P[Log(X)*-XY < log(Y)] $$ and I am lost on how we can continue next. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote does not make sense.

You are given that

$$X\sim\text{Exp}(2)$$

$$(Y|X=x)\sim\text{Exp}(x)$$

Assuming that you are requested to find $f_Y(y)$ you have to use the following

$$\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & =\int f_{XY}(x,y)dx\\
& = \int_0^{\infty}2x e^{-x(2+y)}dx\\
& =\frac{2}{(2+y)^2} \underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}(2+y)^2x e^{-x(2+y)}dx}_{=1}\\
& =\frac{2}{(2+y)^2}\mathbb{1}_{[0;\infty)}(y)
\end{align} $$

The integral in the brackets is 1 as it is the integral of a $\text{Gamma}[2;(2+y)]$

Comment: how did you get the joint pdf?

Comment: @Henry : $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)$

Comment: Oh I see that makes sense. However, I still don't get why there are 2s in your joint pdf. Isnt the exponential distribution $\lambda e^{-\lambda y}$ and since $\lambda$ is equal to x, we get  $xe^{-xy}$

Comment: @Henry :$f(x)=2e^{-2x}$ and $f(y|x)=x e^{-xy}$

Now you surely know that

$$f(x,y)=f(x)f(y|x)$$

do the multiplication and you get the requested result.

Comment: @Henry : by the way did you forget to accept my answer?

Comment: Yep I accepted it. Sorry didn't know about accepting answers